# I have selected a Linked Trigger for a new rule created using CiviRules, so why do I see the error " Select Trigger is a required field "?

Tags: civirules

We're on CiviCRM 4.6.19 and Drupal 7.50.

I've just added and installed CiviRules 1.2 from master.

I'm trying to create my first rule. I selected "Membership is changed" as the Linked Trigger. Other settings are in the screenshot.

Yet, when saving the new rule, I see the error message "Please correct the following errors in the form fields below: Select Trigger is a required field" and I can't save the new rule.

I'm going to start from scratch to see if there is *another* trigger setting I missed.

Any clues to fixing the error or removing the error message are appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: I've [filed an issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/94) and I've started a list of Triggers, Conditions and Actions that definitely work [here](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/wiki)

[image: Screenshot with error message]

Comment: Not all of the triggers is thoroughly tested yet. It lists all available triggers, but to actually test if they work, is not being done. So, if no-one has used that exact trigger, it could be very well be a minor issue that blocks it entirely. Maybe you are the first to trigger on membership? I am basically using Contributions and Activities as triggers, so I don't know. You should file an issue in the github page, and then maybe someone can give you technical advice on how to fix it. Generally speaking; some of the triggers, most of the conditions, and all of the actions have been tested

Comment: Flying thanks so much. I'll file an issue on GitHub. And I'll look around for a list of the triggers, conditions and actions that do work. If you can point me to that, great and thanks. I added and installed the Email API extension as well but still don't see Send an Email in the list of actions.

Comment: I don't think I know of anyone making such a list... But I use these triggers regularly: Activity added, Contribution added, Recurring Contribution added, Daily group member check, Entity is tagged, Contact is added to group. Strange to hear that Email API extension didn't work. It might be a version issue though, I am running on CiviCRM 4.4

Comment: Thanks, going to propose a Wiki page on the repo for such a list. Just filed the issue here - https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/94

Comment: If you think it is a good idea, you might suggest (or take initiative) to make such a list, where users could report which triggers, conditions and actions they are using (and is working)

Comment: Yup started a list on the repo wiki page here - https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/wiki

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed on September 1, 2016 - see the closed issue on the CiviRules GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/94)